# If I install 22.04 on my XPS 13 now, will it automatically get support that Dell adds later?

Tags: drivers, dell, 22.04

The XPS 13 Developer Edition comes with Ubuntu pre-installed, and is supposed to be specially configured to work well with Ubuntu. But I remember reading that basically, Dell just makes sure all the hardware has proper drivers, and contributes anything they write upstream. So if you do a fresh install, you'll still get the same benefits as if you kept the pre-installed OS. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

With this in mind, I was wondering if I could install 22.04 on my XPS 13 DE now, and then once Dell supports 22.04 (usually in a few months), I'll receive updated drivers, etc? Or is that not how it works?

Comment: You're likely to get a much better answer from Dell than from us, and their answer will be fact-based instead of (likely) opinion as here.

Answer (score 1):

The official Dell website usually recommends to Ubuntu users to get their drivers and driver updates from the default Ubuntu repositories whenever possible. Let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.